# Facebook send dialogue authentication

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I’m creating a custom share to facebook functionality, which has been more complicated than I originally thought.

I’ve had to create a facebook app and then use It’s ID to get it going.

If you try to share the page on facebook, it gets you login to facebook(if not logged in), then it requests access to your profile(only on your first share), and then proceeds to share dialogue to let you share it.

However I’ve noticed that other sites including youtube and BBC, that they don’t request access to share on facebook, It will take you straight to the share dialogue instead.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Code using is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId      : '*APP_ID*', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
        link       : '*LINK*'
    });
    $('.share-print .facebook > a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                facebookSend();
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        console.log('Logged in');
                        facebookSend();
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not logged in');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        console.log('Logged in');
                        facebookSend();
                    } else {
                        console.log('Not logged in');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
    var facebookSend = function() {
        console.log('facebookSend started');
        FB.ui({ 
            method: 'feed',
            display: 'iframe',
            link: '*PAGE_LINK*'
        });
    }
</script>
```